# Ruby on Rails rake task - CSV::MalformedCSVError -- Allow forward slashes in cell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Here's a quick example of my CSV file

```
name,xyz,find_id,phase_id
TRACE / TRACK,,60,1
```

and I have a rake task that looks like this

```
namespace :sample do
  task :import => :environment do
    exampl1 = []
    CSV.foreach('lib/tasks/example_file.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
        example1 << XYZ.new(row.to_hash)
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

But it generates

```
rake aborted!
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 27).
```

I am actually using my UI to help build a "database" csv file of items, and it includes forward slashes. I'm also going to be manually updating this csv file as well so I really need it to be as accepting as possible.

Is there any way that I can this continue even if there's quotes or anything in this first field? If it's a comma separate value file, I don't see why a forward slash matters.

Comment: Are you sure the slashes are the problem? I can read that two line CSV with `CSV.foreach` just fine. If you're building this CSV then you should use the CSV library to build it and you should quote everything just to be safe; CSV can be a surprisingly finicky and unpleasant format to work with. You might want to `cat -vet` your CSV file to see if it contains the bytes you think it does.

Comment: Perhaps the line ending type rather than the slashes?

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I tried inspecting the data as much as I could but I ended up just writing my own few lines of code to work around this. Not sure what the issue is exactly but I will try again shortly. I simply replaced the slash with a slash and it worked again. Perhaps sublime text editor is removing something else that is actually unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SmarterCSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)

```
 require 'smarter_csv'
 data = SmarterCSV.process '/tmp/example.csv'
```

This gives you an array of hashes:

```
=>  [{:name=>"TRACE / TRACK", :find_id=>60, :phase_id=>1}]
```

Comment: Why is this better than using something in the stdlib like `CSV.table` ?

Comment: it has a lot more features, e.g. you can get hashes which you can use for creating models directly; it has more options than the stdlib; and it can also process the CSV data in batches.